# Draw manual segue to myself

Tags: xcode, segue

I have a view controller contains a table view that displays list of items.  Each item could contains list of items (or could be a leaf).

To drilldow the list items, I would like to create a show/push segue, kinda in recursively way, but I seem not able to draw the manual segue to the view controller itself?

Is it supported?

Comment: Just to confirm you want a manual segue with the source and destination view controllers being the same? Is there a reason it has to be a manual segue btw? And not trigged by selecting a cell?

Comment: The reason is that based on the selected cell, it could be one of the two manual segues: one to go to itself for showing the sub categories. The other will go to the detail item view controller if the selected item is a leaf.

Comment: Ah I see! I shall post an answer with a way to do it (as I don't think you can have a manual segue to itself!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Rich mentioned, this is probably not doable as for today.  There are two workaround/solutions I can think of:

- Instaniate the vc programatically from storyboard and programatically
  use navigationController to push it.  (I think this is what Rich was
  talking about.)
- Embed the View Controller in another Navigation Controller and draw
  the manual segue to the Navigation Controller.

I choose the 2nd one just because it is very easy and more visual in storyboard. The first one should just work, too.

Answer (score 1):

I was playing around with it just after leaving that first comment - I don't think you can have a manual segue to the same view controller!

The best thing to do would be to give that view controller a storyboard identifier (e.g `Selection` and then create an instance of that view controller with (in Swift):

```
let subCategoryVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Selection") as! SelectionViewController
```

or in Objective-C:

```
SelectionViewController *subCategoryVC = (SelectionViewController *) [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Selection"];
```

(Docs for [`UIStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboard_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIStoryboard/instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:))

You could put that in your table view section method along with a manual segue to the leaf view controller.

(The code above assumes the view controller with the table view is called `SelectionViewController`!)